# Scan string untill find a specifc character in a string

Tags: java, android, string

how do I get the contents of a string to find a specific character? Eg

String s = "The National Weather Service said a "large and deadly" tornado hit south of Oklahoma City the day after storms in Iowa, Illinois, Kansas and Oklahoma. < div Class='mf-viral' > < table border='0' > < tr > < td valign='middle' > < a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/165664155387/u/218/f/640350/c/34625/s/2c2c8c75/a2.htm" > < img src = "http://da.feedsportal.com/r/165664155387/u/218/f/640350/c/34625/s/2c2c8c75/a2.img" border = "0" / > < / a>" ;

I like to have a string that contains only "The National Weather Service said a" large and deadly "tornado hit south of Oklahoma City a day after storms in Iowa, Illinois, Kansas and Oklahoma." And ignore everything from the "< div class ..."

Comment: what do you wanna do with the character? Find the index, make computations?

Comment: I want to ignore the part that is after the "<div ..." to display only the description that is before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can do the following:

```
String input = //paste the content here ;
int end = input.indexOf('<');
String result = input.substring(0, end);
System.out.println(result);
```

This will print the desired result in your case.

If you want to make a generic function that extract a piece from the sentence, until it reaches some character, you can just change the `input.indexOf('<');` statement with `input.indexOf(char c);` and provide the character, where you want to break the sentence. This would work with the agreement that this is the first occurence of the character.

Comment: This is the code for your case. Go for it

Answer (score 0):

String has a String.indexOf(char) which returns int position of the first found char. Your question sounded like this so here. For more help need more info and specific question.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.